# When Transferring Data Between GAE Apps Does It Write To Property Indexes I Have Disabled?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a model with 15 properties and indexed=False set for each of them. When I write an entity of this model it does not write to the property indexes for those properties however when I transfer that model from one app to another it appears to write those property indexes in the new app.

My test is that I have 3000 entities in my original MS app that I want to transfer to my new HR app. In the MS app I have no indexes (defined in index.yaml) and all property indexes are turned off. When I transfer these entities to the new app (using the copy tool in Datastore Admin) it uses all 50,000 writes available in the free quota before it finishes copying all the entities.

I would suspect that since the property indexes are disabled in Python code (my model classes) the Datastore Admin tool probably does not have this information so it assumes it needs to write all property indexes in the new app (or the remote_api assumes or whatever is actually doing the write).

If I am right that this is what is happening is there any way to transfer the entities without having the property indexes written? I could write my own export/import code that uses my Python model classes but I was hoping there was some built in way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the Python code is what defines whether the properties were written indexable or not, the data about whether a particular property is indexed is transferred when entities are moved between apps, so the property should remain unindexed on the new app. You can test this, however, by executing a query in the new app's admin console for the property in question - if it's unindexed, no results will be returned.

If you have composite indexes defined in your new (HR) app, those indexes will be written to for any indexed properties when you copy the entities over. You can save some quota by deleting those indexes until your data is copied, and recreating them then.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nick.

The properties in the source app originally had indexes on them (before GAE pricing changes) but now I have turned them off. If the properties were originally indexed in the source app does the code that transfers entities think they need to be indexed in the destination app? Does disabling the indexes in the source app fix this?

Comment: It appears that a model in the source app that was written while properties were indexed will keep its indexes after being transferred to the new app. I performed a query in the admin interface to confirm this.

I am guessing this is related to the datastore not deleting existing indexes for properties of entities that were written to the datastore before indexing was disabled.

This makes me believe I need to re-write all entities in the source app to make sure the indexes are cleared out before transferring to the new app.

Comment: @BryceCutt That's correct - index data is stored with each individual record, there's no way for the datastore to interrogate your model definitions.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That clarifies things for me.